# Configuring load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to use a load more button to load 40 divs (id="dreamz")

```
<div id="dreamz">
<button class="accordion" id="borderz">The lunar light<a>2018.12.09</a></button>
<div class="panelz">
  <table>
  <th width="50%">
  <img src="assets/images/dream.jpg" width="100%"/>
 <th class="descrip" style="vertical-align: top;" width="50%">
  <p>This is the description</p>
  </th>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript I use is:

```
 $(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 5).show(); 
    $("#load").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 5).show(); 
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ 
            alert("No more dreams");
        }
    });
});
```

This anchor tag is what I use as the button

```
<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
```

I already tried [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) but it didn't work. I use CSS to hide the dreamz id.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having all 40 divs on the page and just showing hiding on click ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to paginate it using wordpress. So I was thinking of adding a load more button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use class="dreamz" instead of id (id is unique).

Then use css to hide class dreamz with "display: none;"

Then your javascript:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".dreamz").slice(0, 5).show(); 
  $("#load").click(function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".dreamz:hidden").slice(0, 5).show(); 
      if($(".dreamz:hidden").length == 0){
          alert("No more dreams");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.dreamz { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>
<div class="dreamz"><p>This is the description</p></div>

<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction, unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: I added code snippet in my answer and it works well. Maybe you have some styles overwritten (something like display: none!important) or error in js code. Can you share a screenshot of DevTools of .dreamz Elements tab and Console tab?

Comment: Thanks heaps! it was a typo. Really appreciate taking time to help me out! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)